# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre los métodos de http como PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, GET....?

Tags: html, webforms, backend, peticiones

Por ejemplo, no entiendo el concepto de que PUT se debe usar para actualizar y no POST, al mandar un formulario desde html con sus valores, una vez recibidos esos valores en el backend, lo que se hace es escribir el código en PHP por ejemplo,  para comunicar con la base de datos y hacer la la consulta de Actualizar un determinado registro, independientemente de si el método fue PUT,POST o GET.

¿Cuál es realmente la diferencia entre emplear uno u otro?

Comment: La diferencia radica en la lógica que implementas para trabajar con los recursos. Una API Rest bien implementada no actualizará un recurso si la petición recibida no es de tipo `PUT`.

Comment: Osea, es mas bien que yo mismo implemente la actualizacion en la base de datos solo cuando el metodo de peticion ha sido put y no cualquier otro?

Comment: Exacto, a eso me refiero, si los métodos HTTP están allí es por un motivo. Si tu API REST permite modificar un recurso usando un verbo `GET`, entonces no está implementada con buenas prácticas. El hecho de que funcione, no implica que se deba usar. No entras a tu casa por la ventana, aunque puedes hacerlo no es una buena práctica, se usa la puerta para eso. Saludos

Comment: Yastaa, ya si me ha quedado super claro, muchas Gracias!!!!

Comment: Además del tema de buena práctica por motivos de semántica (si utilizas GET se entiende que estás pidiendo algo, si utilizas POST se entiende que estas enviando algo, si usas DELETE estás borrando algo, etc.), el utilizar los verbos correctos puede ayudar a filtrar peticiones en el servidor. Por ejemplo, se pueden crear reglas de firewall para evitar llamadas de tipo DELETE que no provengan de un determinado rango de IPs. Si utilizases POST para todo te sería más difícil conseguir esto.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Según la respuesta de ***ilpaijin*** en SO inglés estas son las diferencias, para saber más sobre ello te recomiendo leer su [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27944729/10518234), esta bien explicada y con ejemplos claros.

El protocolo dicta lo siguiente:

- Usa **[GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET)** cuando necesitas acceder a un recurso y a información
  relativa, no necesitas alterar o modificar el estado de esta
  información obtenida.
- Usa **[POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST)** cuando necesitas enviar cierta información al servidor.
  Ejemplo: de un formulario para guardar la información del formulario
  para su uso más adelante.
- Usa **[HEAD](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD)** cuando necesitas acceder a un recurso y recuperar solo las
  cabeceras de la respuesta, sin obtener ninguna información del
  recurso.
- Usa **[PUT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT)** cuando necesitas reemplazar el estado de cierta información
  ya existente en el sistema.
- Usa **[DELETE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE)** cuando necesitas borrar un recurso (relativo a la URI que
  envias) en el sistema.
- Usa **[OPTIONS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS)** cuando necesitas saber que tipos de métodos de respuesta
  soporta el servidor. Se usa para el CORS.

Te pongo unos links a MDN web Docs donde explican y ponen ejemplos sobre cada uno de ellos y otros más por si quieres leer sobre ello e informarte mejor.

Eespero que te sirva.

Answer (score 3):

HTTP es un protocolo de comunicación para el envío de ficheros de hipertexto con enlaces y demás. Y como todo protocolo, tiene unas reglas, y sus comandos tienen una semántica concreta.

El comando `GET` se utiliza para pedir un recurso a una máquina, como una página web HTML, imágenes, etc. La única respuesta de la máquina (servidor) debería ser el recurso si lo tiene, o un mensaje de error. Si lo tiene te responderá con un mensaje `200 OK` con el recurso que pediste incrustado en dicho mensaje.

Si lo que quieres es enviar información al servidor, por ejemplo a través de un formulario, lo normal es utilizar el método `POST`, que envía datos para que el servidor los procese. La respuesta del servidor debería ser solamente un indicativo del estado de dicho procesamiento.

Por otro lado, el método `PUT` está enfocado a la actualización de un recurso del servidor, teniendo también otras diferencias, como la URI suministrada.

Más información sobre los diferentes métodos y usos del protocolo HTTP en [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocolo_de_transferencia_de_hipertexto#M%C3%A9todos_de_petici%C3%B3n), y en el [RFC 1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945), así como en las posteriores revisiones del mismo.

También tienes [aquí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:C%C3%B3digos_de_estado_HTTP) información sobre los códigos de respuesta de HTTP, que es lo que la máquina servidora responde ante una petición.

**Edición:**

Si bien puedes utilizar un `POST` para pedir un recurso, no está bien hacerlo. En primer lugar, rompe con la semántica del protocolo. Y en segundo lugar, los 3 métodos que mencionas no son intercambiables en todas las situaciones.

La diferencia más clara entre un `GET` y un `POST` es cómo se le comunica al servidor cualquier tipo de información extra. Una petición `POST` tiene un cuerpo en el que se añade la información que se le quiere enviar, como por ejemplo los campos de un formulario rellenados por un usuario.

En una petición `GET`, en cambio, la información que se le envía al servidor (que deberían ser cosas como filtros de búsqueda, etc) se mete directamente en la URL de la petición.

Así una petición `GET` se vería de la forma siguiente:

`GET http://www.google.es/search?q=http+get HTTP/1.1`

Más algunas cabeceras con meta información (lenguaje, user-agent, tipo mime, etc).

Donde lo que está a la derecha de la interrogación es la información extra que se le suministra al servidor a la hora de pedir un recurso, si hay más de un argumento se separan por símbolos de &.

En cambio una petición `POST` indicaría la información extra, obtenida a menudo mediante formularios, en el cuerpo del mensaje, no en la URL, quedando como:

`POST http://www.google.es/search HTTP/1.1`

Esto último, por supuesto, es solo un ejemplo.

Además, el método `POST` te permite enviar datos de diferentes maneras: como texto plano, como una cadena de texto al estilo `GET` pero en el cuerpo, o como un dato de bloque (multipart), con lo que te da más flexibilidad a la hora de enviar muchos datos al servidor (como al subir un fichero de código a GitHub, por ejemplo, imagina tener que codificar todo un fichero en la URL).

Comment: Siii, si entiendo que se usan para pedir un recurso de forma distinta, pero no entiendo la diferencia, porque al fin y acabo puedo pedir los diferentes recursos solo usando POST, y tendre los mismos resultados, y si quiero actualizar lo que sea, solo necesito recuperar los parametros de un formulario, independientemente del metodo empleado, ya que luego aplicare un lenguaje de backend y hare mi peticion aparte con esos parametros

Comment: Eso de que el `GET` no admite la datos en el `BODY` ... no se de donde lo has sacado.

Comment: Creo que no he dicho que el `GET` no tiene `BODY` en ninguna parte. Si ha parecido que lo dejaba implícito, no es así. Claro que tiene cuerpo, pero lo que quiero decir es que por norma general la información en un `POST` se mete en el cuerpo, mientras que en un `GET` en la propia URL.

Answer (score 2):

Para interesados, he encontrado mas informacion sobre esto, y esque cuando hablamos de formularios **HTML**, estos solo admiten los metodos **GET y POST**, si decidimos hacer algo como por ejemplo `<form action="localhost/prueba.html" method="HEAD"></form>` o con PUT, o cualquier otro que no sea GET/POST, el navegador automaticamente convertira esos metodos a GET. Por lo contrario, si queremos usar si o si estos metodos, estan implementados en JS, es decir usando **AJAX**, deberiamos poder hacer peticiones con **TODOS LOS METODOS.**
Para mas informacion : https://www.it-swarm.dev/es/html/usando-el-metodo-put-en-forma-html/941772569/
Espero que sea de ayuda! Saludos

Comment: Aqui dejo enlce https://www.it-swarm.dev/es/html/usando-el-metodo-put-en-forma-html/941772569/ , lo que me referia con Ajax, esque si hacemos una peticion con jquery, axios o otra libreria de ajax, podemos usar todos los Metodos, como PUT, DELETE u otro que no sea GET/POST

Comment: Hecho, gracias!!